# Desencriptar Base64 jQuery en C# ¿Qué es lo que está mal?

Tags: c#, jquery, criptografía

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
           
            $("#testLink").click(function () {
                // llavepem hmac
                const llaveBase64 = "cOHQ9GW5fUyCbiKk6kEXCdkxT2nB3db1c6SqqXWV14k=";

                // La llave se encuentra en base 64 es necesario quitarla
                const llave = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(llaveBase64);                                 
                $("#resultado").text(llave);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrsasign/8.0.12/jsrsasign-all-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<a href="#" id="testLink">probar</a>
</p>
<code>
<label id="resultado"></label>
</code>
```

Justo como me lo mencionó @Phi en otro post, fué necesario desencriptar la respuesta, pero al pasarlo de Javascript a C# no logro obtener nada similar.

Esto es lo que obtengo **JS**:

```
70e1d0f465b97d4c826e22a4ea411709d9314f69c1ddd6f573a4aaa97595d789
```

Según parece la librería `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse()` lo que hace es encriptar, pero no tiene sentido que encripte cuando se le está pasando un string en Base64:

```
cOHQ9GW5fUyCbiKk6kEXCdkxT2nB3db1c6SqqXWV14k=
```

necesito obtener esa misma llave desde el codebehind, ya he probado tantos methodos que si los pego aquí serían 10 páginas. algunos son:

```
 public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return text;
    }
    public static string Base64DecodeString(string inputStr)
    {
        byte[] decodedByteArray = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(inputStr.ToCharArray(), 0, inputStr.Length);
        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedByteArray, 0, decodedByteArray.Length);
        return (text);
    }
```

Comment: de donde sale CryptoJS ?

Comment: donde asignas estos UTF-8, UNICODE y ASCII que mencionas has probado ?

Comment: Hola, a tu pregunta: dedonde sale CryptoJS? no estoy seguro, supongo que de `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrsasign/8.0.12/jsrsasign-all-min.js`
a tu pregunta de `UTF-8 y ASCI`: de diferentes métodos que he encontrado en la web para desencriptar y de este ultimo viene del método `CreateToken()` que contiene el `return` de 
`Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hashmessage);`
`Encoding.Unicode.GetString(hashmessage);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código en C# no es equivalente.  Utilizando `llave` como ejemplo:

```
const llave = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(llaveBase64);

$("#lbl1").text(placa);
```

Aquí tienes un objeto que contiene los bytes de la data.  Cuando invocas a `text`, jQuery intenta obtener la representación como texto del array de bytes y la librería CryptoJS que estás utilizando lo que hace es devolver los números en formato hexadecimal.  Lo que estás viendo como `70e1d0f465b97d4c826e22a4ea411709d9314f69c1ddd6f573a4aaa97595d789` es en realidad cada byte convertido a texto.

```
70 e1 d0 f4 65 b9 7d ...
```

Si te das cuenta, siempre son números entre 0 y 255 en base 16.

En el código C# lo que estás haciendo es (simplificando):

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

string llave = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Estás obteniendo los bytes igual que en JS pero la diferencia es que estás tratando de interpretarlos como si los bytes representaran caracteres con codificación UTF8, por eso devuelve símbolos que no tienen sentido.  Para que fuera igual tendrías que traducir los bytes a números hexadecimales.  Podrías usar una función así:

```
public static string FromBase64ToHexString(string input)
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

    // BitConverter hace la transformación de bytes a hexadecimal
    // solo que lo devuelve en un formato así: D0-A1-2B-FF...
    // para eso son las llamadas de Replace y ToLower
    // para que quede igual que en JS
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes)
                       .Replace("-", string.Empty)
                       .ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

En el resto de variables también hay problemas similares, necesitas revisar cual es la representación exacta que tienes que usar en cada caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Diego Torres, me acabas de salvar de un gran apuro, y la respuesta te agradezco mucho más que me hayas explicado el porque de las cosas. Me has enseñado algo muy importante. Me dices que necesito revisar cual es la representación exacta, como haría eso?

Comment: A lo que me refería es que tienes que ver el código de JS y fijarte si lo que estaban usando era los dígitos hexadecimales como en la llave o lo bytes directamente, eso depende de cada campo, analizando con detenimiento.  Si lo convertías en string entonces usar la cadena hexadecimal.